# Auto close brackets in GNOME text editor

Tags: gnome-text-editor

Is it possible to enable auto close brackets on Gnome text editor ?

Comment: If you want to write code, use something like VSCode or Sublime Text instead.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Gnome Text Editor a.k.a. `gedit` has some plugins `sudo apt install gedit-plugin-bracket-completion` to get something similar.